# Long computation AJAX causing duplicate controller Play Framework controller action calls

Tags: ajax, playframework, playframework-2.0

Basic Problem:
If I make an AJAX call to a controller method that performs a long computation (60 seconds or greater), I get a duplicate thread that comes in and follows the same path of execution (as best as I can tell from stack trace dumps -- and only one, this doesn't continue happening with the second thread).  This appears to only happen when the controller action is called via AJAX.  This can easily be replicated by creating a dummy controller method with nothing in it by a Thread.sleep() call that returns when finished.

I've tested this in a method that's loaded without an AJAX call and it doesn't produce the rogue thread.  I tried various forms of AJAX calls (several forms of jQuery methods and base JavaScript) and got the same result with each.  I initially thought it might be a thread problem so I implemented the dummy method using Promise(s) (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaAsync, and http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaAkka) and AsyncResult, but it had no effect.

I know that the two threads are using the same execution context.  Is that causing the problem here?  Is it avoidable by moving the long computation to another context?  Any ideas as to where this second, duplicate thread is coming from?

Controller Method (Long Computation):

```
public static Result test()
{
    Logger.debug("*** TEST Controller entry: threadId=" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    for(StackTraceElement e : stack)
    {
        Logger.debug("***" + e.toString());
    }

    Promise<Void> promiseString = Akka.future(
            new Callable<Void>() {
                public Void call() {
                    try
                    {
                        Logger.debug("*** going to sleep: threadId=" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                        Thread.sleep(90000);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        //swallow it whole and move on
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            }
    );

    Promise<Result> promiseResult = promiseString.map(
            new Function<Void, Result>() {
                public Result apply(Void voidParam) {
                    return ok("done");
                }
            }
    );

    return async(promiseResult);
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if it might be the ajax call timing out and doing a retry causing the second call?

Comment: @johanandren That was my initial thought, but does not appear to be the case.  Watching the network with Firebug I see the initial AJAX GET and that is all.  It's still actively waiting when the second controller action thread comes in.  Also, the response I get back in the jqXHR textStatus is 'error' rather than 'timeout'.